# How to add a popup box when clicked on an SVG icon?

Tags: html, svg

[popup example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5YAB.png)

I only want to use CSS and JS to make this kind of popup when I click on my svg icon

```
<a class="n05">
 <svg><use xlink:href="#icon-93f"></use></svg
 ><span class="label">Text</span></a>
```

Comment: You're expected to make an effort and ask a more specific question. What have you tried?

Comment: I was looking through this https://sabe.io/tutorials/how-to-create-modal-popup-box but I am unable to find something for SVG, they are all buttons.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't much care what element you attach event handlers to.

Comment: But how can I use my SVG? It's <button class=.....
How can I use my SVG instead?

Comment: `<svg class=`? I don't understand your question, which is why you're expected to show an attempt. Lengthy comment discussions shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first section is **Javascript**, then **Css** and finally some **Html**.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<h2>Click This icon to display the model</h2>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<i id="myBtn" class="fas fa-band-aid"></i>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h1>Popup</h1>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```